# Let $G=S_5$ be symmetric group. Let $H=\langle(1,2,3)\rangle$ be subgroup of $G$. How many subgroups of $G$ which is conjugate to $H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G＝S_5$ be symmetric group.
Let $H=\langle(1,2,3)\rangle$ be subgroup of $G$.

How many subgroups of $G$ which is conjugate to $H$?

My try: $H$ is sylow $3$ subgroup of $G$, so the number of conjugate subgroups are $1$ or $4$ or $10$ because it decides $5!÷３＝40$ and $\equiv 1\bmod 3$.
And $H$ is not normal subgroup, so the number of conjugate subgroups of $H$ is $4$ or $10$.
But I cannot proceed from here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $S_5\ne\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Hint: All order three elements generate a $3$ sylow subgroup in $S_5$, (with redundancy) try just counting them, and remember that the Sylow theorems tell you that the conjugation action is transitive of $3-$sylow subgroups so counting conjugates of a given order $3$ subgroup is the same as counting order $3$ subgroups.

Comment: $(1,2,3)$ is not an element of $S_5$. Undoubtedly you meant the 3-cycle $(123)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, *e.g.* Herstein's Topics in Algebra uses the notation with commas for the cycles.

Comment: @CAB Thanks for the news. Feels strange to me. May be handy if the range includes double-digit integers, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subgroup of $S_5$ which is conjugate to $H$ will be of the form $\langle(a,b,c)\rangle$, for some subset $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ of size $3$.  There are ${5\choose 3}=10$ such subsets.  Note that $\langle(a,b,c)\rangle=\langle(c,b,a)\rangle$, so there is at most a unique subgroup conjugate to $H$ for each of these $10$ subsets.

Finally note that for any subset $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, there is a permutation in $S_5$ taking the set $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{a,b,c\}$.  This element will conjugate $H$ to $\langle(a,b,c)\rangle$.

Thus all $10$ of the subsets correspond to subgroups conjugate to $H$.